# How to move file pointer back by one integer?

Tags: c++, file

Say I have a file containing integers in the form

```
1 57 97 100 27 86 ...
```

Say that I have a input file stream fin and I try to read the integers from the file.

```
ifstream fin("test.txt");
int val;
fin>>val;
```

Now I am doing this action in a while loop where at one period of time, I want to move my file pointer exactly one integer back. That is if my file pointer is about to read the integer `27` when I do `fin>>val`, I want to move the file pointer such that it can read the integer `100` when I do `fin>>val`. I know we can use `fin.seekg()` but I have used it only to move the file pointers by characters, not by integers.

Probably this is a naive question. But can someone please help me out?

Comment: This is not a naive question and this is not a trivial thing to do, you'll have to determine the length (in characters) of the number in order to move the file pointer accordingly. Why not just read all the numbers, store them in a vector and then read it backward ?

Comment: If you made the file binary instead of text it would be easier.  Re-reading a number from a file when you already know what number it is does seem a little daft though

Comment: Just curious: does my answer help? If not, what is wrong about it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`tellg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg) after each read to save the pointer to be used later on with a `seekg`.

You could also take the implementation of `<<` and modify it with a function that also returns the number of characters you have advanced each time. Where to find the source code of `operator<<` is not something where I could easily help you with.

Answer (score 3):

In your case it is not an integer, but a text representing a number. Because of this you will have to move backward character by character until you find a non-digit one (`!isdigit(c)`).

As one of the commenters below pointed out, you may also pay attention to a the 'minus' sign in case your numbers can be negative.

Comment: If they are all positive. If they can be negative you might need to include the `-` character depending on where you are in the characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [istream::unget()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/unget)

Comment: "Attempts to decrease the current location in the stream by one character" rather than an interger?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin("test.txt");
    int val;

    bool back = false;
    for (int i = 0; fin >> val;)
    {
        if (!back && val == 27)
        {
            while (i++ < 2)
                while (!std::isspace(fin.unget().rdbuf()->sgetc()));
            back = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you have 2 times `while (!std::isspace(fin.unget().rdbuf()->sgetc()));`?

Comment: @Antonio Because the pointer to the current character in the buffer will be just *after* 27. I need to skip back to the next whitespace twice because I want to get just *before* the previous integer. I could have done this differently with a `for` loop for instance.

Comment: @Antonio Assuming there is one space between each number, this should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

first argument is the file name, second argument is the numbers index, program displays the number at the index and then displays the previous number (counting from zero)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 3){
        std::cout<<"argument error!\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream read;
    read.open(argv[1],std::ios::app);
    if( read.is_open() ){
        std::vector<int> numbers;
        int temp;
        while(read >> temp){
            numbers.push_back(temp);
        }

        std::cout<<"1) "<<numbers[atoi(argv[2])]<<"\n2) "<<numbers[atoi(argv[2]-1)]<<std::endl;

            read.close();

    }else {
        std::cout<<"file open error!\n";
        return 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{

    ifstrem file("fileName.txt");
    char var=file.get()://now this will move file pointer one time forward
    /* Seekg(n,position) accept two arguments.The number of bits and position
    from where to move the file pointer
    if value of n is negative then file pointer will move back.
    */
    file.seekg(-1,ios::cur);//to move the file back by one bit from current position
    
    retur
```

n 0;
}